# multiple functions in summrise_each() with multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

The following works. I am sure there is a better solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean, median)) %>%
  gather(var, val, -Species) %>%
  separate(var, c("variable", "summary"), sep = "_") %>%
  spread(summary, val)
```

Comment: I am just trying to learn `dplyr`/`tidyr`. I am not sure if I am using `summarise_each()` properly.  Particularly, is there a way to avoid the last three steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gather` your relevant variables *first*, then do your summary calculations.

For example:

```
iris %>% 
  gather(var, val, -Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species, var) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean, median))
```

Not only is the code more concise, it would also be faster since you have less to do:

```
fun1 <- function() {
  iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean, median)) %>%
    gather(var, val, -Species) %>%
    separate(var, c("variable", "summary"), sep = "_") %>%
    spread(summary, val)
}

fun2 <- function() {
  iris %>% 
    gather(var, val, -Species) %>% 
    group_by(Species, var) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(mean, median))
}

library(microbenchmark)
library(compare)

microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2())
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#  fun1() 6.725408 6.950540 7.572307 7.202001 7.648250 12.326271   100
#  fun2() 3.346863 3.475828 3.784302 3.535849 3.824349  6.580824   100

compare(as.data.frame(fun1()), as.data.frame(fun2()), allowAll = TRUE)
# TRUE
#   [variable] coerced from <factor> to <character>
#   sorted
#   renamed
#   renamed rows
#   dropped names
#   dropped row names
```